# RadListView pullToRefresh memory leaks

Tags: angular, memory-leaks, nativescript, radlistview

I am building NS and Angular app and I am using RadListView with pullToRefresh enabled. I noticed that after some usage app starts to slow down. After investigation I saw just some elements like images are leaking.

Here is memory snapshot after just one pull to refresh hit:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah453.png)

Here is general comparison after more refreshes and you can see that memory is increasing on many elements and even more images leaking

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42YU8.png)

and here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOaUY.png)

Here is my code (I believe I am not doing anything special):

```
<RadListView #myListView [items]="items" [height]="scrollViewHeight" 
(pullToRefreshInitiated)="onPullToRefreshInitiated($event)" pullToRefresh="true">
<ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
    <GridLayout columns="auto, *, 22, auto" rows="*" class="item-holder" (tap)="onLayoutTap($event)"
        backgroundColor="white" padding="0">
        <StackLayout col="0" row="0">
            <Image [src]="item?.profilePicture"
                class="-thumb img-circle image-border-{{item?.status}}" width="60" height="60">
            </Image>
            <Label text="&#xe9d9; {{ item?.text5 }}" class="icon review-text"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout col="1" row="0">
            <Label [text]="item?.text3" class="h2"></Label>
            <Label [text]="item?.text1" class="h5 list-item--subheader"></Label>
            <Label [text]="item?.text2" class="h4" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <GridLayout columns="*,auto" class="additional-info">
                <Label col="0" text="{{ item?.text8}} {{ item?.text9}}" class="h5 cherry-text"
                    textWrap="true"></Label>
                <Label col="1" [text]="item?.text7" class="h5 cherry-text" textWrap="true"></Label>
            </GridLayout>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout col="2" row="0" rowSpan="2" class="status-bar status--{{item?.status}}"></StackLayout>
    </GridLayout>
</ng-template>
```

and ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'px-received-items',
   templateUrl: './received-items.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./received-items.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class ReceivedItemsComponent implements OnInit {

private leftThresholdPassed = false;
private rightThresholdPassed = false;

items: any

get scrollViewHeight() {
    return screen.mainScreen.heightDIPs - 250;
}

@ViewChild('myListView', { read: RadListViewComponent, static: false }) myListViewComponent: RadListViewComponent;

constructor(
    cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private dataGQL: DataGQL,
    private authService: AuthService,
) {}

ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.fetchData();
    });
}

async onPullToRefreshInitiated(args: any) {
    this.fetchData();

    const listView = args.object;
    listView.notifyPullToRefreshFinished();
}

private fetchData() {
    this.dataGQL.watch({ id: this.authService.authData._id })
        .valueChanges
        .pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe(response => {
            this.items = response.data.inquiries.receivedInquiriesn
this.cd.markForCheck();
        });
}

}
```

Any ideas how to solve that leaking?

Comment: **To leak** and **leaking** - not "to leack" or "leacking" .....

Comment: Okay, but where do you assign `items`?

Comment: @MacDonald inside graphql api call

Comment: dataGQL.watch() ? You're subscribing every time you use pullToRefresh

Comment: Peter - yes, thats how observables in rxjs works. But if you notice it is not leak - because there is take(1)